# Finding Taylor series of $\sin(5z)$

Tags: trigonometry

What is the Taylor series of $$\sin(5z)-5\sin(z)$$

at $z_0=\pi$

I am confused whether to substitute $5(z-\pi)$ or $5z-\pi$ into the Maclaurin series of $\sin(z)$.

Comment: Just in the Taylor series of $\sin(z)$ put $5z$ and then make the difference term to term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $5(z- \pi)$ and observe that

$\sin(5z)=-\sin(5(z-\pi))$ and $\sin(z)=- \sin(z- \pi)$